# Update profile info does not work

Tags: support, profile-page, stackexchange.com

I try to update my profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/317335/guettli

Clicking on the **Update profile info** then I choose copy from Stack Overflow.

On Stack Overflow I fixed the typo: https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961/guettli?tab=profile

Correct is http://thomas-guettler.de/ on Stack Exchange the "r" is missing.

Updating does not work.

Even caching should not be the root of the problem, since I tried the same yesterday.

Am I doing something wrong, or there a bug?

Comment: Not reproducible. My changes are updating correctly. Are you receiving any console error?

Comment: Do you have JavaScript whitelisting (like [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript))? The post *[Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)* contains information about which domains are needed. Profile updates ***do*** require more domains than normal.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I have no special JS configuration. I do not use NoScript. All other web pages work.

Answer (score 0):

today it worked. I have no clue what was wrong. But who cares? I am happy. Thank you.